# Change column name and make a default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run:

```
rails generate migration AddShowmsgColumnToPublishers show_msg:boolean
rake db:migrate
```

but now, I want to change the name of the column to "hide_msg" and set a default value by false.

How can I do that please?

I read that I have to do something like:

**first step:**

```
rails generate migration FixColumnName

class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :publishers, :show_msg, :hide_msg
  end
end
```

**second step:**

```
rails generate migration add_default_value_to_hide_msg
```

**third step:** edit the file into:

```
def up
    change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, :default => false
end

def down
    change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, :default => nil
end
```

**and finally:**

```
rake db:migrate
```

but is there no other way with one command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify both in a single migration too. e.g.

```
class FixColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_column :publishers, :show_msg, :hide_msg
    change_column :publishers, :hide_msg, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def down
    rename_column :publishers, :hide_msg, :show_msg
    change_column :publishers, :show_msg, :boolean, :default => nil
  end
end
```

And then run `rake db:migrate`. works fine for me :)

Comment: just a reminder that when working with up and down methods, make sure that the first code on the down method reverses the last code on the up method. this is ok with this implementation since the orders doesn't matter for this particular migration

Comment: @jvnill Thanks for the clarification.. But in this case we cannot use `change` method as the `change_column` has the name of the remaned_column. So it will throw error while rolling back the migration. :)

Comment: yep i get that. i would've answered the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do rake `db:rollback STEP=2`.

You can substitute 2 for however many migrations you want to go back.

And then simply do:

```
rails generate migration AddHidemsgColumnToPublishers hide_msg:boolean

rake db:migrate
```

Comment: thank you..
I made: db:rollback STEP=2, but I had a mistake.. I wanted to do: db:rollback STEP=1.. how can I change it?

Comment: `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version` and if the table has not been dropped from the database outside of Rails, `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=my_version`

Comment: how can I know what is my version?

Comment: this is the number of the migration file that I want to do the migration, right?

Comment: yes right and you can also determine the version by seeing the migration table in database.

Comment: just a reminder that this wont work unless you edit the migration after doing the rollback.  when you run rake db:migrate after, the show_msg column will still be added unless you delete the migration (which is not advisable if you've already committed the file on the remote repository). the right way is to create a new migration that renames the column.

Comment: @jvnill yes you are right that you need to edit the table also and delete the `show_msg` column after rollback otherwise it will create it again when we do `rake db:migrate`.